# Only get certain items in TFS Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using `Team Foundation Server`, plugged-in to `Visual Studio 2012`.

We have a wide range of projects and solutions, but rarely need everything on our local machines.

Is there a way using `Team Explorer` to get latest only on certain solutions in different folders, in bulk, using a single click (or as close as possible)?

> **Development**
>
> > Project 1 `Get this`
> >
> > Project 2 `Ignore this`
> >
> > Project 3 `Get this`
>
> **Framework**
>
> > Project 1 `Ignore this`
> >
> > Project 2 `Get this`

...in one click.

Comment: In VS Team Explorer, right-click on the folder you want and Get Latest..

Comment: I mean in bulk, so if I have 6 solutions all in different folders, how do I get latest on all of them in one operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of thing, I use `tf.exe` in a command file on my desktop. That way I just have to double-click the .cmd file. It has the added bonus of being a lot quicker than firing up VS.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET DEVENVPATH2013=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE

Echo Getting latest files...

REM Navigate to to Solution's mapped folder on local machine, e.g. for me it is D:\Socrates\Development, and issue a get against the relevant TFS folder for the Solution ($/Socrates/DEVELOPMENT)

D:
CD \Socrates\Development
"%DEVENVPATH2013%\tf.exe" get $/Socrates/DEVELOPMENT /recursive

REM Copy the above 3 lines for each separate Solution you want to Get Latest for


Echo Finished.
Echo.
```

BTW, I'm guessing that you will need to edit the DEVENVPATH to be 11.0 instead of 12.0

So for your example, and assuming your local folder mappings are directly under C drive, you will want something like:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET DEVENVPATH2012=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE

Echo Getting latest files...

REM Navigate to to Solution's mapped folder on local machine, e.g. for me it is D:\Socrates\Development, and issue a get against the relevant TFS folder for the Solution ($/Socrates/DEVELOPMENT)

C:
CD \Development\Project1
"%DEVENVPATH2012%\tf.exe" get $/Development/Project1 /recursive

C:
CD \Development\Project3
"%DEVENVPATH2012%\tf.exe" get $/Development/Project3 /recursive

C:
CD \Framework\Project2
"%DEVENVPATH2012%\tf.exe" get $/Framework/Project2 /recursive


Echo Finished.
Echo.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you setup a workspace that points at the root of the folder structure that you b have listed and in the workspace cloak the folders that you do not want you can simply get latest on the workspace in a single command in the UI and it gets what you want.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490753.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's two things you can do

1. Get a portion of the directory structure by opening Source Control Explorer, right clicking a node in the folder tree and selecting "Get Latest Version" from the context menu. This will get the selected folder and all sub-folders.
2. Open a Visual Studio solution directly from source control. Double click the SLN file in Source Control Explorer. Visual Studio will get all the items referenced by the solution and its projects. You can then get latest on just the solution items by right clicking the top of the solution tree in Solution Explorer and selecting "Get Latest Version (Recursive)" from the context menu.

Comment: My original question wasn't clear on getting projects from different folders while excluding others in the same folder, so have updated with an example. Hope it's clearer now.